# opencart payumoney not display even after installation Success messege

Tags: opencart, payumoney

I am integrating payumoney to opencart 3.0.2.0 version . as per the documentation

i make the installation successfull

[image]

even after that in payment list payumoney is not visible

is there any log in which i can check ?

Comment: payu and payumoney are same and they had not release version for opencart 3.x, and opencart 3 had so many change like tlp files are replace with twig, you have to search on opencart marketplace for oc 3.x version

Comment: check this can help you :  https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31903

Comment: thnx prashant , i jst reconfirmed that , Now i am installing for opencart 2.2